# auto.arima stationary parameter

Tags: r, arima

I fit data with `auto.arima` function in variant with exog.
If I'm right, when exog is used, linear regression is used to fit data and residuals are fitted with arima, so coeffs of linear part must be always the same, but:

**Var 1:**

```
model = auto.arima(y,stationary=TRUE,stepwise=FALSE,parallel=TRUE,
        num.cores=cn,approximation=FALSE,xreg=train_x,x=y)
```

**Output 1:**

```
13
Series: y 
Regression with ARIMA(3,0,0)            errors 

Coefficients:
         ar1     ar2      ar3        T      R
      0.7887  0.5917  -0.8989  -0.0076  4e-04
s.e.  0.0507  0.0836   0.0506   0.0035  2e-04
```

---

**Var 2:**

```
model = auto.arima(y,stepwise=FALSE,parallel=TRUE,num.cores=cn,
        approximation=FALSE,xreg=train_x,x=y)
```

**Output 2:**

```
13
Series: y 
Regression with ARIMA(0,0,0)(2,1,0)[12] errors 

Coefficients:
        sar1     sar2    T    R
      1.2310  -0.3639    0    0
s.e.  0.1379   0.1565  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: The fitting is simultaneous, not stepwise, therefore the coefficients in the linear regression part vary with any variations in the ARIMA part.

Comment: Thanks for answer. So, there is no way to vary only ARIMA part?
There is stepwise parametr, but I suppose it is for other purpose ?

Comment: Normally you would prefer simultaneous estimation, so the variation is a good thing. If not, then run a regression with `lm`, take the residuals and model them with `auto.arima`. That will fix the regression estimation in the first stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fitting is simultaneous, not stepwise, therefore the coefficients in the linear regression part vary with any variations in the ARIMA part.

Normally you would prefer simultaneous estimation because it is more efficient (statistically, not computationally), so the variation is a good thing. If not, then run a regression with `lm`, take the residuals and model them with `arima` or `auto.arima`. That will fix the regression estimation in the first stage and you can fiddle with the ARIMA part for the residuals independently.